# use awk to identify multi-line record and filtering

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to process a big data file that contains multi-line records, example input:

```
1  Name      Dan
1  Title     Professor
1  Address   aaa street
1  City      xxx city
1  State     yyy
1  Phone     123-456-7890
2  Name      Luke
2  Title     Professor
2  Address   bbb street
2  City      xxx city
3  Name      Tom
3  Title     Associate Professor
3  Like      Golf
4  Name
4  Title     Trainer
4  Likes     Running
```

Note that the first integer field is unique and really identifies a whole record. So in the above input I really have 4 records although I dont know how many lines of attributes each records may have. I need to:
- identify valid record (must have "Name" and "Title" field)
- output the available attributes for each valid record, say "Name", "Title", "Address" are needed fields.

Example output:

```
1  Name      Dan
1  Title     Professor
1  Address   aaa street
2  Name      Luke
2  Title     Professor
2  Address   bbb street
3  Name      Tom
3  Title     Associate Professor
```

So in the output file, record 4 is removed since it doen't have the "Name" field. Record 3 doesn't have Address field but still being print to the output since it is a valid record that has "Name" and "Title".

Can I do this with awk? But how do i identify a whole record using the first "id" field on each line?

Thanks a lot to the unix shell script expert for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work.  There are MANY ways you could do this, even in awk.

I've spaced it out for easier reading.

Note that record 3 doesn't show up because it's missing an "Address" field, which you identified as required.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        # Set your required fields here...
        required["Name"]=1;
        required["Title"]=1;
        required["Address"]=1;

        # Count the required fields
        for (i in required) enough++;
}

# Note that this will run on the first record, but only to initialize variables
$1 != last1 {
        if (hits >= enough) {
                printf("%s",output);
        }
        last1=$1; output=""; hits=0;
}

# This appends the current line to a buffer, followed by the record separator (RS)
{ output=output $0 RS }

# Count the required fields; used to determine whether to print the buffer
required[$2] { hits++ }

END {
        # Print the final buffer, since we only print on the next record
        if (hits >= enough) {
                printf("%s",output);
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! It took me a little time to digest your solution and then I learned a lot from it!!! :) really appreciated! Saved me so much time as well as learned so much from this :)

Comment: almost +1 - mostly very nice. You can drop the `NR==1` clause. The question appears to be slightly ambiguous as to whether "Address" is required. However, I read it as *not* being required (thus record 3 should be output). When I run your script with the "Address" line commented out, I get all four records instead of just 1-3, in spite of the fact that "Name" is empty for record 4. The reason for this is that your selector `required[$2]` brings into existence an array element corresponding to each field name merely by being referenced *and you're not checking that it's equal to `1`*.

Comment: You can verify this by adding `for (i in required) print i` at the end of the `END` block. You must also check to see whether `$3` is empty (`required[$2] == 1 && $3`). The extra entries will still be created in the array, but by explicitly checking the value there won't be any false positives. I believe the record should be excluded if a field is missing *or empty*. @nanshi can verify if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: Good points, mostly.  The `NR==1` block is indeed redundant.  I put it in to make the condition on the next block more understandable.  As for "Address", that's why I noted it explicitly in my answer; the OP said '*say "Name", "Title", "Address" are needed fields*'. And I can't duplicate your results when commenting the Address line. Perhaps you're using an uncommon version of awk?  I tested on nawk 20110810 (FreeBSD) and gawk 4.0.1.

Comment: As for the `required[$2]` thing, in the END block, try `for (i in required) print i "=" required[i];` to see what will be evaluated.  A `required[$2]` that exists but is empty is evaluated the same as if it doesn't exist.  In awk, 0 or "" evaluates as false, and 1 or /./ evaluates as true.  These array elements are noise, but don't affect the function of the script.

Comment: I thought of another potential issue. Although the OP's sample data doesn't show it, sometimes there is more than one Address field (sometimes they might be distinguished by a suffix though) or there might be a malformed record where a field might be inadvertently repeated. Let's assume that this is a required field and another required field is missing. The hit counter might then be satisfied, but incorrectly. I different approach would need to be taken in order to protect against this. Perhaps keeping an array of flags would do it.

Comment: I think we'd need to know from the OP whether multiple fields of the same name would exist.  I'd be more inclined to expect "Address" and "Address2" rather than multiple "Address" fields.  But I don't know where this comes from, so I can't speculate.  Nice pastebin variation, btw.  :)

Comment: I'm using gawk 3.1.6 and 4.0.0 and get the results I described with both. However, you're correct about the true/false evaluation. It's the `&& $3` that makes the difference. And that depends on whether the OP wants to exclude only records with missing required fields or also those with empty required fields. So I give you a well-deserved +1.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson and ghoti thanks a lot for your help! I've incorporated all the suggestions and checked almost all the edge cases, it works fine. The issue left is that the file is in unicode, and i dont know how to match the field in unicode..

Comment: I should rephrase my question as - How do i write "Name" in unicode within required["Name"]=1 in the script?

Comment: @nanshi You should be able to use Unicode strings for indices. My tests seemed to work fine. What specifically are you having trouble with? What version of AWK do you have and what's the environment (OS, distribution, etc.)?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I was testing the script using bash on MacPro. It was all working fine with my test input file. Then i run the script on cygwin that is installed on a Windows server and the script didn't give me any output. I tried both awk and gawk on that server. gawk on the server is version 4.0. And the encoding of the real input file is UTF-8.

Comment: @nanshi: Check to see if the file has Windows line endings. That could cause problems. You can fix the file using `dos2unix` or other methods, if that's the case.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson i dont know whether the file was generated by DOS or unix...not sure how to check, but if i open the file in vi, i saw "^@"is before each normal character...i am still searching on google to try to find some hint :(

Comment: @nanshi: You can run `dos2unix` on the file even if it's not needed - it won't do any harm. You can do `cat -v filename` and if you see "^M" at the end of the lines, the file has Windows (DOS) line endings.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I did try to use dos2unix earlier, but the command said "Skipping binary file ..."...Ahhh, "cat -v filename" gave me "^M^@" as the last two char (guess 8byte each, two of them made a unicode)...What should i do next? :)

Comment: by the way, since the file was really big (hundreds of gigabytes) i used "head" command to get 100 lines out to a file, then used 'cat -v'...hope this kept that mystery character at the end of the file.

Comment: [other info] i've checked that both awk and gawk(on cygwin of that server) are GNU Awk 4.0.0. Also, I processed this file days ago using awk and awk was able to identify each line of record using it's default RS.

Comment: @nanshi: Well, I don't know why you're not getting any output. If you want, we can continue this on chat (just click the link above the comment input box). I would need to look at some lines from the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12006/discussion-between-nanshi-and-dennis-williamson)

Answer (score 3):

I am not good at awk, but I'd solve this in Perl. Here is a Perl solution: for each record, it remembers the important lines and whether the name and title was seen. At the end of a record, the record is printed if all the conditions are met.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($last, $has_name, $has_title, @record);
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($id, $key, $value) = split;
    if ($id != $last and @record) {
        print @record if $has_name and $has_title;
        undef @record;
        undef $has_name;
        undef $has_title;
    }
    $has_name  = 1 if $key eq 'Name';
    $has_title = 1 if $key eq 'Title';
    push @record, $_ if grep $key eq $_, qw/Name Address Title/;
    $last = $id;
}


__DATA__
1  Name      Dan
1  Title     Professor
1  Address   aaa street
1  City      xxx city
1  State     yyy
1  Phone     123-456-7890
2  Name      Luke
2  Title     Professor
2  Address   bbb street
2  City      xxx city
3  Name      Tom
3  Title     Associate Professor
3  Like      Golf
4  Name
4  Title     Trainer
4  Likes     Running
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your perl solution! I will try it out later. Now i will go with awk since i still need to modify the script a bit for my next need which is not posted here.